# How to return object from action

Tags: objective-c, sudzc

I am trying to work with sudzc.com soap client.

This is how I invoke my web service:

```
Example_ManagerService* soapService = [[CCExample_ManagerService alloc] init];
[soapService getVehicle:self action:@selector(getVehicleHandler:) id: currentVeh_id.intValue];
```

Now this is calling getVehicle and passing the result to the action getVehicleHandler.
So far so good.
However, is there a possibility to get the result back from the getVehicleHandler function?
currently it is returning void:

```
- (void) getVehicleHandler: (id) value {
```

I would like to not do all the work in the handler but pass the object back to the calling object.

How do I do that?

Comment: From what you've posted (using `self`), it looks as if the handler is already a method in the calling object.  Is it not?

Comment: You can create set the calling object as a delegate and call a method which will process the returned vale. but I would rather suggest you to design properly, by design means application architecture design. BTW you don't have to submit to getVehicleHandler you can create your own method but you have to make a response delegate to your self in order to get called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning a value you can set the object inside the handler

```
- (void) getVehicleHandler: (id) value {
        ...do your staff...
        myObject=myNewValueForMyObject
}
```

Comment: there is no option for doing that